# dnn:label Not a Known Element

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm going through some DNN tutorials and in one tutorial, for Edit.ascx the author says to add:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="label" Src="~/controls/LabelControl.ascx" %>
```

so that `<dnn:label ID="lblName" runat="server" />` can be used. However, VS2013 gives a warning for dnn:label saying that "**Element 'label' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.**" I've tried to view other DNN source and I also get the same warning so I presume it has to be a setup issue. I made sure that the properties in my project are configured to:

- Start URL: http://dnndev.me/
- Servers: Local IIS Project Url: http://dnndev.me/desktopmodules/myproject
- Override application root URL: http://dnndev.me

The LabelControl.ascx file is indeed located at ~/controls/LabelControl.ascx and the web.config file isn't missing from the root directory at dnndev.me.

Does anyone know why I am getting such a warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a warning. My templates get that warning in pretty much all instances.

You can ignore it.